Vue - @click doesn't fire when Button is placed above the modified object (with Bootstrap btn)
This works:

This doesn't work

delete last - button is responsible for deleting lines from the "Products Table".
I can't understand what the problem here is. Does an event always need to be placed after the modifying elements? This doesn't really make sense to me.
Below the code:
<template>
...
<button @click="removeItem(itemID)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">delete last</button>
<table>...<table>
...
<tamplate>

<script lang="ts">
...
 methods: {
    removeItem(elementID: number): void {
      let itemIndex = this.products.findIndex((el) => {
        return el.id === elementID
      })
      if (itemIndex !== -1) this.products.splice(itemIndex, 1)
      else alert("no such item")
    }
  }
...
</script>

This works perfectly when

delete last - button is placed above the "Products Table"

whereas it
doesn't work when

delete last - button is placed below the "Products Table"


Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem, the question cannot be asked in general.It's unknown what "doesn't work" means. Does nothing happen, or alert is triggered, or else? You can debug what happens with this.products on your side.  You need specify keys in case it's iterated with v-for, and array index isn't one

Hi @EstusFlask,
"Doesn't work" means no reaction at all. But I just realized it has to do with Bootsrap when I disable the Bootstrap imports it works. Somehow Bootstrap is disturbing the execution

Unless you use bootstrap-vue, this is a potential real problem because bootstrap modifies dom directly as any other vanilla js lib and can interfere with vue

Look for errors in the browser console

your images don't match your description

@EstusFlask you are right. I don't use bootsrap-vue since this only supports bootsrap 4 and meanwhile the latest version is 5.3. Do you maybe know what styling framework + vue is considered good practice in general? maybe tailwind.css?

@telli There's bootstrap-vue-next, needs to be thoroughly checked if all the comps you're interested are ok ready because it's not prod ready yet. Primevue gives a good DX and pretty much customizable, also integrates with tailwind if you prefer their styling

@telli my guess it's not a good decision to throw a framework due 1 bug only. i would say it's better to debug and find the culprit to know better how vue and bootstrap interact in this particular case

@AlexanderNenashev I was able to fix it. The bug just disappeared but was related to some js interfering problem. It is not only because of this bug but more to find a general approach / compatible stack that would be a good fit with vue.

@EstusFlask Meanwhile, I tried tailwind.css and vuetify and I am surprised how easily and straightforward all work together.

@telli you cannot manipulate DOM with JS in Vue freely, because Vue uses Virtual DOM and destroys your manual DOM changes or you DOM changes breaks Vue. You should work with virtual nodes in render functions


Your images don't match your description
The event handler should work regardless of element's placement
As mentioned in comments Bootstrap could interfere (DOM manipulations doesn't work good with Vue's VDOM)
Make sure in the devtools the event handler is properly attached to the button:



Also provide any console errors

Otherwise the question could be considered as lacking of debugging details.

Sorry if the images are misleading. Here an explanation:


The images differ only in the position of the "delete" button placement. In the first picture where the button is placed below the code is running as expected in the latter one where the button is placed in above the v-on:click handler doesn't fire.


Yes, that was also my expectation and it indeed does. The problem here is bootsrap interfering with vue


The event handler is attached correctly and works just fine when I don't use any bootsrap



@telli try to wrap  and  in separate 's?
